# How to parse a .dat file line by line in C++

Tags: c++

So i am trying to parse some data from a file. The program is supposed to look at the third value at each line, and if the string is equal to 'compare' look at each last value of the line and store the min and max for all lines. However, when i try to compile it i get an error on:

```
  std::stringstream lineStream(line);
```

and when converting string to a float in order to compare and store the last and min value:

```
   strtof(Value);
```

Here is my code:

```
using String = std::string;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  std::ifstream inputFileStream;
  inputFileStream.open("data.dat");

  if(!inputFileStream.is_open()){
    std::cout<<"error";
    return 0;
  }

  int count;
  inputFileStream>>count;
  inputFileStream.ignore(1, '\n');

  String minValue;
  String maxValue;

  for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
    String line;
    std::getline(inputFileStream, line);
    std::stringstream lineStream(line);

    String first;
    String second;
    String third;

    std::getline(lineStream, first, ',');
    std::getline(lineStream, second, ',');
    std::getline(lineStream, third, ',');

    String compare="compare";

    if(Line_Identifier->compare(compare)==0){

        String last;

        std::getline(lineStream,last, ',');

        if(strtof(last)>strtof(maxValues)){
            maxValues=Value;

        }
        else if(strtof(Value)<strtof(minValues)){
            minValues=Value;
        }
    }
}
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @SeanPianka For std::istringstream lineStream(line) i get: variable 'std::istringstream lineStream' has initialized but incomplete type on the ) in (line).

Answer (score 2):

You should use the "input string stream", `std::istringstream`.

```
std::istringstream lineStream(line);
```

For `strtof`, you should use `std::strtof`.

Comment: I still get the same error. For std::istringstream lineStream(line) i get: variable 'std::istringstream lineStream' has initialized but incomplete type on the ) in (line).

Comment: @FedericoArribas, please post a [mcve]. That will be helpful in tracking the problem.